# MySQL trigger which triggers on either INSERT or UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Is there a way to create MySQL trigger which triggers on either UPDATE or INSERT?

Something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_apps_affected BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ...
```

Obviously, the above don't work. So, any workarounds without creating two separate triggers?
I need this in order to update running counter on another table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no shorthand form - you must create multiple triggers - one for each event.

The [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) says:

> `trigger_event` indicates the kind of statement that activates the trigger. The trigger_event can be **one** of the following:
>
> **INSERT**: The trigger is activated whenever a new row is inserted into
>   the table; for example, through INSERT, LOAD DATA, and REPLACE
>   statements.
>
> **UPDATE**: The trigger is activated whenever a row is modified; for
>   example, through UPDATE statements.
>
> **DELETE**: The trigger is activated whenever a row is deleted from the
>   table; for example, through DELETE and REPLACE statements. However,
>   DROP TABLE and TRUNCATE TABLE statements on the table do not activate
>   this trigger, because they do not use DELETE. Dropping a partition
>   does not activate DELETE triggers, either. See Section 12.1.27,
>   “TRUNCATE TABLE Syntax”.

Answer (score 4):

While it is impossible to put a [trigger on multiple events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html), you can define the two triggers to merely call another stored procedure and, with that, cut down on the amount of code you need to commit. Just create the separate triggers to do nothing but, say,

```
CALL update_counter();
```

and put all of your actual work into the procedure. The triggers would then be a simple

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_apps_affected BEFORE INSERT ON table
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
CALL update_counter();
END;
```